# Shared reources with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, resources

I have a PC (WinXP) with 4 USB modem's. Each modem has its port assigned individualy and work correctly. I want to send and receive information from all 4 ports at the same time, and for that I have using threads that work independently one on each port. I'm not sure if at any time any action required to use a shared resource which would generate a conflict. Any experience? Thank in advance...

Answer (score 0):

What shared ressource?

- A modem is not shared, you have to lock it for your application.
- If one thread only talks to one modem, what exactlyx is shared on it?

So, there is nothing regarding the modems that is a shared ressource to start with.